# Gedit: How to insert backslash \ in search and replace regex

Tags: regular-expression, gedit

I'm trying to comment out some lines in c++ by matching them with a regex, and replacing with the match preceeded by `\\`. But instead, gedit performs no replacement, and the search+replace dialog gives a little `!` by the replace field.

The regular expression I'm using is `^(.*kBlack[^\n]+)\n` which matches correctly (any line with kBlack in). My replacement is `\\\\\1\n` - i.e. `\\` to escape the second `\` and produce a single `\`, repeated for two `\`'s, followed by `\1` for the submatch, then a newline `\n`. But no luck.

No variation in the number of starting slashes seems to give me what I'm looking for. What are the rules for properly inserting backslashes?

Comment: Not an answer, but: why don’t you just use `//`?

Comment: ............................. oh my god.  I can't believe I've been trying to insert \'s for a C++ comment, when a comment is // .
Well, ... I suppose it would still be nice to know. Thanks for pointing out that blunder though!

Comment: Probably a bug in the regex engine (see [`glib/gregex.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/gregex.c))... If you place your cursor over that exclamation mark for a couple of seconds it will pop up the exact error message... Your regex & replacement work fine here with v. `2.52`. However, it looks like this version isn't bug-free either as trying to replace any char with a backslash (that is, escaping it, so using a double backslash as the replacement) results in a `stray final \ ` error...

Comment: Actually, your replacement doesn't work properly with v. `2.52` as it inserts only one backslash... to insert two backslashes I have to use `\\\\\\\\\1\n`... lol... what a mess...

Comment: Yikes! I  mean i fiddled with a variety of attempts, but i don't think i tried *that* many backslashes! 
Thanks for pointing to the file, if this becomes a real issue I'll know where to look.